# How to click on small buttons placed close to each other on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, touch

I am trying to run an old application on Windows 8. It has really small buttons for close and minimize that are placed close to each other, so I keep clicking the wrong buttons.

What utilities/apps can solve my problem, whether by allowing me to zoom in on a selected area or by any other method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the Magnifier app?

Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, type `Magnifier`, and launch the app.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Even better, just use `Win`+`+` ;)

Comment: @OliverSalzburg didn't know that shortcut! Nice one!